# JS - Auto-initialisation behaviour of `let` vs `var`

Tags: javascript, scope, variable-declaration, hoisting, variable-initialization

In 'Chapter 5: The (Not So) Secret Lifecycle of Variables' of 'You Don't Know JS Yet', the section titled [*"Uninitialized Variables (aka, TDZ)"*](https://ydkjs.netlify.app/docs/scope-closures/secret-lifecycle/#uninitialized-variables-aka-tdz) says that the only way to initialise an uninitialised `let` variable is with an assignment attached to a declaration statement (because an assignment by itself is insufficient). This is illustrated by the following example.

Example 1:

```
let studentName = "Suzy";
console.log(studentName);   // Suzy
```

In the next example, the declaration and initialisation is split up - the `let` variable is declared on line 1 and then initialised on line 2:

Example 2:

```
let studentName;
// or:
// let studentName = undefined;
    
studentName = "Suzy";

console.log(studentName);
// Suzy
```

Under this example, there is a callout that reads:

> That's interesting! Recall from earlier, we said that `var studentName;`
> is not the same as `var studentName = undefined;`, but here with `let`,
> they behave the same. The difference comes down to the fact that var
> studentName automatically initializes at the top of the scope, where
> let studentName does not.

**Question 1:**

I'm not sure how Example 2 above demonstrates that `let studentName;` and `let studentName = undefined;` are equivalent. Earlier in the chapter, the section titled [*"Redeclaration?"*](https://ydkjs.netlify.app/docs/scope-closures/secret-lifecycle/#re-declaration) uses the following example to illustrate that `var studentName;` is not the same as `var studentName = undefined;`:

Example 3:

```
var studentName = "Frank";
console.log(studentName); // Frank

var studentName;
console.log(studentName); // Frank <--- still!

// let's add the initialization explicitly
var studentName = undefined;
console.log(studentName); // undefined <--- see!?
```

In the above example, the second `studentName` declaration is basically a no-op since `studentName` has already been declared. But how does this relate to the `let` example (example 2)? i.e. How does example 2 show that `let studentName;` and `let studentName = undefined;` behave the same?

**Question 2:**

The second sentence of the callout above says, "The difference comes down to the fact that `var studentName` automatically initializes at the top of the scope, where `let studentName` does not." But doesn't `let` automatically initialises to `undefined` if no value is specified at the time of declaration (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#temporal_dead_zone_tdz))?

**Edit:**

My bad - regarding Question 2, the second sentence of the callout does make sense. The [specs](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-let-and-const-declarations) say that if a `let` declaration does not have an initialiser expression, then that let-declared variable will be assigned a value of undefined when that `let` declaration is ***evaluated***. Whereas if a `var` declaration is made without an initialiser, then that var-declared variable will be assigned `undefined` when it is ***created*** ([see](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-variable-statement)).

However, I'm still unsure about Question 1.

Comment: Yes, the book may be misleading here… both `var` and `let` get “hoisted”, i.e. declared at the top of their scope (function for `var`, block for `let`). However, `var` allows redeclaration, whereas `let` does not; and `var` is automatically initialized to `undefined` everywhere in the scope, whereas `let` is only initialized to `undefined` after its declaration; accessing a `let` variable before its declaration results in a `ReferenceError`.

Answer (score 2):

One of the important differences:

> The difference comes down to the fact that **var studentName automatically initializes at the top of the scope, where let studentName does not.**

is not illustrated by the example snippets in your question, since you don't try to access the variables declared with `let` before they're declared.

> In the above example, the second studentName declaration is basically a no-op since studentName has already been declared. But how does this relate to the let example?

With `let`, re-declarations are not permitted - rather, there must be a *single* statement in the code somewhere where the variable name can be determined to come out of the temporal dead zone and get referenced by other parts of the code. Until a variable has been fully initialized - that is, until the interpreter has run across the `let someVarName` line (no matter whether something is assigned to it with `=` or not) - the variable name cannot be assigned to or retrieved.

Aside for that, `let someVarName` is pretty similar to `var someVarName` - `let` will assign a value of `undefined` to the variable at that moment, and the `var` will give the variable a value of `undefined` at the beginning of the scope.

> "The difference comes down to the fact that var studentName automatically initializes at the top of the scope, where let studentName does not." I'm not sure what this means as I always thought let automatically initialises to undefined if no value is specified at the time of declaration

See this for an example:

```js
// Not permitted:
console.log(studentName); // Error
let studentName;
```

Compare to:

```js
// OK
console.log(studentName);
var studentName;
```

With `let`, you cannot reference said variable until the interpreter has run across the `let someVarName` line.